# TikZ based \boxed construct is causing pdflatex to hang

Tags: tikz-pgf

In standalone code this works for me, drawing a nice red colored box around my equations (based on TikX `\underbrace` like replacement that I use without any trouble):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{tikzNodeNum}

\newcommand{\xmyBoxed}[2]{%
\tikz[baseline]{%
    \node[draw=red,rounded corners,anchor=base] (m#2)%
    {$\displaystyle#1$};%
}%
}

\newcommand{\myBoxed}[1]{%
   \stepcounter{tikzNodeNum}%
   \xmyBoxed{#1}{\thetikzNodeNum}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\myBoxed{
a + b = c
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\myBoxed{
a + b = c
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\myBoxed{
a + b = c
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However, in larger documents, pdfLaTeX hangs when it processes a use of this.  I haven't been able to reproduce the hang in any sort of MWE.  Could somebody who knows TikZ syntax take a look above and see if there are any syntax errors that could be causing this trouble (when it works, it does draw my boxed equations nicely).

Comment: You could have produced a MWE that is easily copyable … syntax looks could. (Though, you will need the `remember picture` option if you ever want to use the node name again.) What is the typical content that you use it with? You can’t use a `&` inside `*align*` environments and expect `amsmath` to align it correctly. Have you seen the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package? It seems you’re re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: As you said this works fine. There is something else in your document that is the culprit, not this code.

Comment: Sorry, made a MWE that is copyable.  I use this typically with equation and dmath environments.  I'll take a look at the hf-tikz package.