# How can I adjust the box around my equation?

Tags: equations, boxes

I currently use the `\boxed{}` command to place boxes around my equations. However, I would like to have more control of the style of the box. Is there a way to do this?

To take a specific example, the figure below shows both the standard `\boxed{}` out put (a) and the desired mock-up (b), where I have increased the box size and increased the border thickness slightly.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for automated features/parameters to increase border width, or are you asking for different line styles/thicknesses etc. around the box?

Comment: My main aim is to increase the box size. Anything else (line thickness, line style, line colour, etc.) would be a bonus.

Comment: You say increase box size.  That might imply scaling the whole object to a larger size (see scalerel package) or your answer might imply keeping the equation the same size and adding border space.

Comment: @Steven: In my opinion, it's quite clear from the image that the OP wants to keep the equation the same size.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Correct.

Comment: No one suggested the _usual_ TikZ overkilling solution, so it's my turn; you may have a look to [\boxed{}, TikZ and colored equation background](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75133/13304) and to [hf-tikz doesn't box around equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101038/13304) (which shows some new option of the hf-tikz package).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Someone is going to suggest a tikz box with multicoloured translucent rounded corners, but before they do I'll observe that `\boxed` is a thin wrapper around `\fbox` so you can use

```
\setlength\fboxsep{...}
```

to set the padding inside the box and

```
\setlength\fboxrule{...}
```

to set the line thickness.